# How to create a vertical line via DOM?

Tags: dom, line

I want to make a vertical line in my table by using DOM...
I can insert row and cell but do not know how to insert vertical line.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Please explain better your question and put an example. What is a "vertical line", in this context?

Comment: sorry. I meant, something like a <hr> line. In HTML, example: <hr size=1>. Can you insert it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<hr>` tag in html and css as follows

> height: 100%;
>   width: 100%;

also u can in php code as follows.

> 

```
<?php
    if(true)
    { 
    echo '<hr>';
    } 
    else
    {
    echo'';    
    }?>
```